# My application build on android but not on iOS because of Pods/PhoneNumberKit

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods

My application doesn't build on iOS.
My dependences in my pubspec.yaml are :
dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
video_player: ^2.7.2
pay: ^1.1.2
flutter_login: ^4.2.1
http: ^1.1.0
sign_in_button: ^3.2.0
flutter_session_manager: ^1.0.3
wakelock: ^0.6.2
crypt: ^4.3.1
flutter_email_sender: ^6.0.2
rflutter_alert: ^2.0.7
url_launcher: ^6.1.14

This is my log

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 13 in debug mode...
Running pod install...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           17,0s
Failed to build iOS app
Uncategorized (Xcode): Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
/Users/hinvi/StudioProjects/smartifice/ios/Pods/PhoneNumberKit/PhoneNumberKit/RegexManager.swift:33:22

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
/Users/hinvi/StudioProjects/smartifice/ios/Pods/PhoneNumberKit/PhoneNumberKit/RegexManager.swift:94:26

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
/Users/hinvi/StudioProjects/smartifice/ios/Pods/PhoneNumberKit/PhoneNumberKit/RegexManager.swift:106:26

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
/Users/hinvi/StudioProjects/smartifice/ios/Pods/PhoneNumberKit/PhoneNumberKit/PartialFormatter.swift:61:34

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
/Users/hinvi/StudioProjects/smartifice/ios/Pods/PhoneNumberKit/PhoneNumberKit/PartialFormatter.swift:95:25

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
/Users/hinvi/StudioProjects/smartifice/ios/Pods/PhoneNumberKit/PhoneNumberKit/PartialFormatter.swift:105:25

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
/Users/hinvi/StudioProjects/smartifice/ios/Pods/PhoneNumberKit/PhoneNumberKit/PartialFormatter.swift:303:31

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
/Users/hinvi/StudioProjects/smartifice/ios/Pods/PhoneNumberKit/PhoneNumberKit/PartialFormatter.swift:331:31

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
/Users/hinvi/StudioProjects/smartifice/ios/Pods/PhoneNumberKit/PhoneNumberKit/PartialFormatter.swift:347:44

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
/Users/hinvi/StudioProjects/smartifice/ios/Pods/PhoneNumberKit/PhoneNumberKit/PartialFormatter.swift:364:30

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
/Users/hinvi/StudioProjects/smartifice/ios/Pods/PhoneNumberKit/PhoneNumberKit/PartialFormatter.swift:392:28

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
/Users/hinvi/StudioProjects/smartifice/ios/Pods/PhoneNumberKit/PhoneNumberKit/PartialFormatter.swift:397:32

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
/Users/hinvi/StudioProjects/smartifice/ios/Pods/PhoneNumberKit/PhoneNumberKit/PhoneNumberKit.swift:310:43

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 13.
```

Thanks for your help

```
flutter clean 
rm -Rf ios/Pods
rm -Rf ios/.symlinks
rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec
pod deintegrate
pod install
```

Comment: Might need a more recent version of Xcode

Comment: My MAC is on macOS Big Sur 11.7.10 and I can't get the latest version of Xcode how need macOS 13.x or more. What can I do